# My script does not recognize my IP

Tags: php, geolocation, geocoding

I use [GEOIPLOC library](http://chir.ag/projects/geoiploc). I created a simple script with this variables:

```
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$my_country_code = getCountryFromIP($ip, "code");
```

and uploaded my script to a server. Result: the variable $ip returns my IP, and the variable $my_country_code returns the code of my country, very good!

That same script uploaded it to another server (http://subdomain.my-domain.com, which belongs to my job). Result: the variable $ip **does not** return my IP, but the IP: 192.168.211.XXX. Therefore, the variable $my_country_code **not** return my country code.

In both cases I use my home pc.

What's going on?

Comment: You have a reverse proxy or load balancer in front of your other server, and its address is put into `REMOTE_ADDR`.

Comment: The proxy should send the original IP in the `X-Forwarded-For` header, and the server needs to be configured to put that into `REMOTE_ADDR`.